# How can I automate camel pack refilling?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-crash-landing

Constantly refilling the camel pack is tedious and time-consuming.

I would prefer a method that does not involve opening a window (crafting, terminal, etc) to refill the camel pack. I have lost count how many times I need to do this in a typical play session and it is daunting how much time is spent on this task.

I followed the tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/ujoTS_mnr30) but am curious if there are simpler setups.

Comment: You could try using Peunamacraft drones, the hi-tech helmets (forgot name and from the same mod) or simply placing hoppers above (and below, alongside chests) the water squeezer machine. The last option requires opening windows, but is semi-automated while the first two require you to be descent way into the modpack's progress tree..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generikb](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJTWU5K7kl9EE109HBeoldA) has come up with a solution using Pneumaticraft's [Aerial Interface](http://www.minemaarten.com/wikis/pneumaticcraft-wiki/pneumaticcraft-wiki-aerial-interface-player-inventory-wrapper/) in [Episode 28 of his LP series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRn7Ul7v0AU). He starts building it around 4:00, and it is built on top of another already existing machine he used before that.

The main idea is to use two Aerial interfaces. Hook them up to a high pressure tube. Connect Itemducts to the bottom of these and install Pneumatic Servos, one going in, the other going out. On the outgoing one, place an empty camel pack on the whitelist and make sure to use NBT data (otherwise it will remove all camel packs). On the ingoing one, do the same using a full pack.

Now, connect both itemducts to a Cyclic Assembler capable of transforming empty camel packs and water bottles to full camel packs. Return the empty bottles to a Fluid Transposer to refill from a water barrel or similar supply.

Comment: I will try this out (assuming I live long enough).